# Angular - how to separate the routes into modules?

Tags: angular, routes, nativescript

I'm working on a NativeScript w/ Angular 8+ app.

I have 2 feature modules: authentication and authenticated.
Right now all my routes are in the one main routing file: app-routing.module.ts

How can I separate my routes into their respective modules and keep everything working?

e.g.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/landing-page", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "landing-page", component: LandingPageComponent },
    { path: "register-client-code", component: RegisterClientCodeComponent },
    { path: "register-via-sso", component: RegisterViaSsoComponent },
    { path: "sign-up-page", component: SignUpPageComponent },
    { path: "home-page", component: HomePageComponent },
    { path: "activities", component: ActivitiesComponent },
    { path: "flexi-balance", component: FlexiBalanceComponent },
    { path: "balance-details", component: BalanceDetailsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I want my home page and feature pages in an authenticated module router and the others in an authentication module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import the feature module (with the respective routes) by using `loadChildren` in your parent-routing file:

```
{
    path: 'authenticated',
    loadChildren: () =>
    import('./authenticated/authenticated.module').then(m => m.AuthenticatedModule),
}
```

AuthenticatedModule internally imports the AuthenticatedRoutingModule

Edit: Check the Angular docs (lazy loading) for more information: https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration